# Python Flask multiple forms leads to Multiple IDs #csrf_token

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am using python 3 and flask in a webproject. I have multiple forms on a single page. Forms have a `hidden_tag()`, which is the `csrf_token`.

The problem is that the id's of all `csrf_token` are the same.

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #csrf_token:
```

I could use ajax or simply use a new page for the form, but I'd like to understand whether there is a fix for that.

I tried to assign a custom id to each `hidden_tag()`:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag(id="tag_1") }}
```

But it tells me:

```
TypeError: hidden_tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

So far I was not able to find a solution.

**EDIT:**

The error is displayed by the browser in the console:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I am trying to add the `hidden_tag`, so it will overwrite the original hidden tag, but I cant figure out how the value is created.

```
hidden_tag = HiddenField('EditUserPasswordHiddenTag', default="the value")
```

That is what I got:

```
<input id="hidden_tag" name="hidden_tag" type="hidden" value="the value">
```

Comment: Non-unique IDs are only a warning. How do you get this message?

Comment: The browser displays the error in the console.

Comment: @Roman create a second csrf token field with a different ID in your form model and call hidden_tag(csrf_fieldname) for the csrk fields.  http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.hidden_tag

Comment: @Rambarun Komaljeet Its not working too, the value gets lost.

Comment: I voted to reopen, because the given link does not answer this particular question about duplicated IDs. None of the answers there mentions this problem. One of the answers (with `prefix=...`) solves it correctly, but as I said, without mentioning it, so the reader looking for an answer cannot know.